# Adding an array of tags to xml root

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I have an array of **xml.etree.ElementTree.Element**. i need to append it into root tag which contains few **Tags** (i.e) **xml.etree.ElementTree.Element**

for Example:

```
<MxGraphModel>
    <root>
       <mxCell id="0"></mxCell>
       <mxCell id="1"></mxCell>
    </root>
</MxGraphModel>
```

My array `['<mxCell id="3"></mxCell>','<mxCell id="4"></mxCell>']`

My final output needs to be :

```
<MxGraphModel>
     <root>
        <mxCell id="0"></mxCell>
        <mxCell id="1"></mxCell>
        <mxCell id="3"></mxCell>
        <mxCell id="4"></mxCell>
     </root>
</MxGraphModel>
```

Comment: are you using numpy arrays or list? in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

data = ['<mxCell id="3"></mxCell>','<mxCell id="4"></mxCell>']
root = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot()

nodes = root.find('root')
for x in data:
    nodes.append(ET.fromstring(x))

print(ET.tostring(root))
```

**Output:**

```
<MxGraphModel>
   <root>
      <mxCell id="0" />
      <mxCell id="1" />
      <mxCell id="3" />
      <mxCell id="4" />
   </root>
</MxGraphModel>
```